# Get percentage of two subselect from DB

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table, and I need to count two different columns in subselect. I've got something like this:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(z.id_contract) AS countOfContracts,
    (
        SELECT COUNT(zml.id_contract) FROM [DW].[dbo].[DW_D_CONT] AS zml 
        WHERE zml.p_akt= 'A' 
        AND d_start_dw > '2013-01-01'
        AND d_start_dw < '2013-01-31'
    ) AS januar,
    (
        SELECT COUNT(zml.id_contract) FROM [DW].[dbo].[DW_D_CONT] AS zml 
        WHERE zml.p_akt= 'A' 
        AND d_start_dw > '2013-02-01'
        AND d_start_dw < '2013-02-28'
    ) AS februar
     FROM ...
```

I need to do something like

```
januar / februar * 100
```

However the alliases doesn't work in subselects. So I thought about something like this:

```
    (
        (SELECT COUNT(zml.id_contract) FROM [DW].[dbo].[DW_D_CONT] AS zml 
        WHERE zml.p_akt= 'A' 
        AND d_start_dw > '2013-01-01'
        AND d_start_dw < '2013-01-31')
    )
    /
    (
        (SELECT COUNT(zml.id_contract) FROM [DW].[dbo].[DW_D_CONT] AS zml 
        WHERE zml.p_akt= 'A' 
        AND d_start_dw > '2013-02-01'
        AND d_start_dw < '2013-02-28')
    )
```

So I am trying to get count of "januar" and "februar" like a subtask (you can see there's different dates), but I always receive 100%. I'm absolutely sure, that count of januar and of februar is DIFFERENT

Can somone help me?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using `OUTER APPLY`:

```
SELECT COUNT(z.id_contract) AS countOfContracts,
       months.jan, months.feb, months.jan / months.feb
FROM ... OUTER APPLY
    (SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN d_start_dw > '2013-01-01' AND d_start_dw < '2013-01-31'
                     THEN 1.0 ELSE 0
                END) as jan,
            SUM(CASE WHEN d_start_dw > '2013-02-01' AND d_start_dw < '2013-02-28'
                     THEN 1.0 ELSE 0
                END) as feb
     FROM [DW].[dbo].[DW_D_CONT] AS zml 
     WHERE zml.p_akt = 'A'
    ) months;
```

This allows you to aggregate all months in a single subquery, which should be more efficient than a separate subquery for each month.

You should also review your date arithmetic.  I'm not sure why you would exclude the first and last days of the month.

Comment: My problem is the division of those two subselects. I receive always 1 (which means 100%). But count for january is not the same as for february. I don't know how it is possible :(

Comment: @MegoSoft . . . SQL Server does integer division.  So, you need to change the values to a floating point/decimal representation.  I just changes `1` to `1.0` to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are not working on an outdated version of sql server (pre 2008), you can use a [cte](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx):

```
;WITH cte as 
(
        SELECT
    COUNT(z.id_contract) AS countOfContracts,
    (
        SELECT COUNT(zml.id_contract) FROM [DW].[dbo].[DW_D_CONT] AS zml 
        WHERE zml.p_akt= 'A' 
        AND d_start_dw > '2013-01-01'
        AND d_start_dw < '2013-01-31'
    ) AS Januar,
    (
        SELECT COUNT(zml.id_contract) FROM [DW].[dbo].[DW_D_CONT] AS zml 
        WHERE zml.p_akt= 'A' 
        AND d_start_dw > '2013-02-01'
        AND d_start_dw < '2013-02-28'
    ) AS Februar
     FROM ...
)

SELECT Januar, Februar, Januar / Februar * 100
FROM cte
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible to do this without using subqueries, like so:

```
select
    count(case when p_akt = 'A' then id_contract end) as total_count,
    count(
        case when p_akt = 'A' and d_start_dw > '2013-01-01' and d_start_dw <= '2013-01-31'
            then id_contract
        end
    ) as januar_count,
    count(
        case when p_akt = 'A' and d_start_dw > '2013-02-01' and d_start_dw <= '2013-02-28'
            then id_contract
        end
    ) as februar_count
from
    [DW].[dbo].[DW_D_CONT]
```

It's generally a good idea to avoid using subqueries wherever possible.

Answer (score 0):

This should work in any MS SQL  version.

```
SELECT
    COUNT(z.id_contract) AS countOfContracts,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN d_start_dw > '2013-01-01' AND d_start_dw < '2013-01-31' 
       THEN  zml.id_contract END)  AS januar,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN d_start_dw > '2013-02-01' AND d_start_dw < '2013-02-28' 
       THEN  zml.id_contract END)  AS februar
FROM ..
```